# How to change views exposed filter default value

Tags: 7, views

So I have this view with exposed filter of taxonomy terms with depth, I had selected some of the terms to limit the selection.

everything works just fine but the issue is that the default value of the exposed filter (combo-box) is set to the latest entry (taxonomy term), and I want to set it to that -All- thing.

I know that if I don't select any of the terms to limit the selection, it'll be set on -All- as default value for the exposed filter, but I don't wanna do that!

the question seems quite simple but I couldn't figure this out! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

in template.php:

```
function MY_THEME_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // dpm($form);
  if ($form['#id'] == 'MY_EXPOSED_FORM_ID') {
    // Modifications go here.
    // example: (change the field name to yours)
    // $form['field_adv_cat_1_tid']['#default_value'] = 'All';
  }
}
```

then clear the cache.

Comment: Thanks xurshid for answer but the thing is I rather to fix it via views itself, if it's not possible I try template.php thing, btw I tried your approach and couldn't make it work, maybe I did sth wrong there, should I replace the ID of my select field in $form['field_adv_cat_1_tid']['#default_value'] = 'All'; instead of field_adv_cat_1_tid ?

Comment: @Sohail 1. This function is a hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() function. You can read about it by this link: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7. 2. open template.php file and paste above code into it, and change MY_THEME to your theme name. Clear cache and use dpm($form) to find the id of your form. Then change MY_EXPOSED_FORM_ID to your form's id.

Comment: @Sohail here is a nice tutorial (unfortunately in russian) - http://xandeadx.ru/blog/drupal/304, shows how to work with Devel

Comment: thanks, the thing is I still couldn't make it work! By the way we can just inspect the form and use the form ID in HTML (easier than devel). I used the below code:

function stme_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
   dpm($form);
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-resellers-page') {
    // Modifications go here.
    // example: (change the field name to yours)
    $form['views-exposed-form-resellers-page']['#default_value'] = 'All';
  }
}

Comment: @Sohail `views-exposed-form-resellers-page` ( `$form['views-exposed-form-resellers-page']`) - is a name of an element? You need to find your desired element's name... Use devel's `dpm($form)` or php's built-in `print_r($form)` or `var_dump($form)` to find it..

Comment: Oh sry I pasted the wrong thing, here's the code: 
function stme_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
   dpm($form);
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-resellers-page') {
    $form['term_node_tid_depth_i18n']['#default_value'] = 'All';
  }
}

but it works! but just based on devel it says that term_node_tid_depth_i18n #default_value is All, but it still shows the last term of mine which is a city name! it must be overriden somewhere, right? is it even possbile? I cleared cache btw

Comment: @Sohail Does 'All' value exist in the options array?

Comment: @Sohail, By default, `Drupal` replace underscore (`_`) in `form id` of the form into dash(`-`) when render HTML of the form. You should use `views_exposed_form_resellers_page` or check with `dpm()` function or `print_r` or `var_dump`.

Comment: Jayendra, Thanks for the hint, I fixed that.
xurshid, Yea it does, if I say resellers?term_node_tid_depth_i18n=All in URL it works the way that it should

Comment: @JayendraKainthola in my project `if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-adverts-advert-term-display') {...}` works fine:) It's a strange..

Comment: @xurshid29, Yes, its strange. As I know that Drupal replace `form id` when render the html of the form.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola I just tested this and found that if I change dashes to underscores, it won't work.. `$form['#id']` only receives dashes..

Comment: @xurshid29, `id` in HMTL form is `views-exposed-form-adverts-advert-term-display`?

Comment: @JayendraKainthola yes. Here you can see it: `<form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="views-exposed-form-adverts-advert-term-display" method="get" action="/category/term/751">`

Comment: @xurshid29, It's interesting. I also need to check this . But, I am sure, if you will check with another form like creating custom form in custom module, it will not work.

Comment: @xurshid29, I have checked `views_exposed_form` and found that `#id` attribute of `form` and `#form_id` is different. I think, as all exposed form has same `form id (views_exposed_form)`, so `views` module is setting different `#id` attribute of the form for each different form.  In `drupal_prepare_form()` in `form.inc`, then if `#id` attribute is not set, its converting `form_id` and setting to `#id` attribute of form.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola Thanks for the clarification, I didn't know about it..

Comment: @xurshid29, I also do not know about this _why `views_exposed_form` working differently_.

Comment: hey -- does anyone know if it's possible to have the default values affect the results from the view? I've followed the steps to create the default values, which works, but the form must be submitted before the results are filtered, which can be confusing to the user. Is it possible to force the "apply" step on initial page load? I'd rather avoid using a javascript solution so if there's a drupal way to do this that would be great. Thanks