# How do I change the default value for a filter?

Tags: 7, views

I want to customize the default value for a filter in view through some custom code.
I have tried the below answer and its not working for me.

```
if ($form['#id'] == 'MY_EXPOSED_FORM_ID') {
// Modifications go here.
// example: (change the field name to yours)
// $form['field_adv_cat_1_tid']['#default_value'] = 'All';
```

}

[How to change views exposed filter default value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98200/how-to-change-views-exposed-filter-default-value)

And I tried these settings also.

```
$form_state['input']['field_program_tid'] = '44';
$view->filter['field_program_tid']->value = "44";
$view->exposed_input['field_program_tid'] = "44";
```

Anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 2):

you can try using hook_form_alter in your custom module.

```
     function yourmodule_name_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id){
//print $form_id to get correct id of the exposed form
    if($form_id == 'views_exposed_form'){
      $form['field_program_tid']['#default_value'] = '44';
//you can unset "all" if you don't need it
      unset($form['field_width_value']['#options']['All']);

     } 
    }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer but I used contextual filter and its working fine.

Comment: cheerio..thats also a clean way...